# Can we use the word "открытие" with the preposition "o"?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, грамотность

I'm curious whether it's grammatically correct to use the word "***открытие***" with the preposition "***o***"?

"*Открытие*" is a verbial noun and stems from the verb "*открывать*", which isn't used with the preposition "*о*". So the noun must not take this preposition either. However, I did   come across enough such examples on НКРЯ("открытие о себе", "открытие о подлинном росте", "открытие о своей страсти", and so on), but I'm still unsure whether they are absolutely right.

Hence, there is a question: Can "открытие" be combined with "о"?

Answer (score 1):

> "Открытие" is a verbial noun and stems from the verb "открывать", which isn't used with the preposition "о"

Yes it is. It is a dated usage (as are usages in your examples), yet.

> - Она придумала свой аристократизм, но она в то же время всем своим поведением открывала о себе людям больше, чем многие вокруг нее, и, хотя и сожгла все свои бумаги, оставила по себе след. *// [Н. Н. Берберова. Железная женщина (1978-1980)]*
> - Всяк, вступавший в эту секту, давал клятву не открывать о ней, под страхом наказания в будущей жизни, ни родителям, ни родным, ни духовному отцу, ни пред судом. *// [Н. И. Костомаров. Русская история в жизнеописаниях ее главнейших деятелей. Выпуск седьмой: XVIII столетие (1862-1875)]*
> - Пусть Иисус жил и действовал подобно пророку, но то, что Он открыл о Себе, не позволяет ставить Его в один ряд с другими мировыми учителями. *// [Александр Мень. Сын Человеческий (1969)] [омонимия не снята]*

As a side note, this premise:

> So the noun must not take this preposition either

is flawed.

Consider the verb *разрешать*. It is not used with the preposition *на*. But its derivative noun *разрешение* is: *разрешение на ношение оружия, разрешение на охоту* etc.